# There is a popular tag called 'accomodation'. Can we rename it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is a popular tag called 'accomodation'. Can we rename it? I don't think I have enough permission to do it.

Comment: I'm sure we would love to *accommodate* your request, but what do you want to rename it to?

Comment: 'Accommodation'?

Comment: Sorry - I thought it was obvious that the word 'accommodation' was spelled incorrectly.

Comment: I was looking for an excuse to use a pun. sorry.  heh

Comment: Understood, but you even spelled it correctly in your comment! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now [done](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accommodation)

Comment: Much appreciated :)